# AWS Cognito - Setting device as remembered does not suppress MFA challenge

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, multi-factor-authentication

I have 2 Cognito user-pools.

First one I have created on **August 20, 2021**. The following is the configuration:

```
{
    "UserPool": {
        "Id": "us-east-2_************",
        "Name": "dev-mobileapp-users",
        "Policies": {
            "PasswordPolicy": {
                "MinimumLength": 8,
                "RequireUppercase": true,
                "RequireLowercase": true,
                "RequireNumbers": true,
                "RequireSymbols": true,
                "TemporaryPasswordValidityDays": 7
            }
        },
        "DeletionProtection": "INACTIVE",
        "LambdaConfig": {
            "PreSignUp": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789009:function:dev-mobileapp-users-presignup-trigger"
        },
        "LastModifiedDate": "2024-02-16T11:13:49.777000+05:30",
        "CreationDate": "2021-08-20T10:59:47.932000+05:30",
        "SchemaAttributes": [
            {
                "Name": "sub",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": false,
                "Required": true,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "1",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "name",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "given_name",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "family_name",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "middle_name",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "nickname",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "preferred_username",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "profile",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "picture",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "website",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "email",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": true,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "email_verified",
                "AttributeDataType": "Boolean",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false
            },
            {
                "Name": "gender",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "birthdate",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "10",
                    "MaxLength": "10"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "zoneinfo",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "locale",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "phone_number",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": true,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "phone_number_verified",
                "AttributeDataType": "Boolean",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false
            },
            {
                "Name": "address",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "updated_at",
                "AttributeDataType": "Number",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "NumberAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinValue": "0"
                }
            }
        ],
        "AutoVerifiedAttributes": [
            "email"
        ],
        "UsernameAttributes": [
            "email"
        ],
        "SmsVerificationMessage": "Your verification code is {####}. ",
        "EmailVerificationMessage": "Please enter this verification code to verify your identity:\n{####}\n\nIf you did not make this request, please email support@abc.com.\n\nThanks,\nThe Abc Team",
        "EmailVerificationSubject": "Your verification code",
        "VerificationMessageTemplate": {
            "SmsMessage": "Your verification code is {####}. ",
            "EmailMessage": "Please enter this verification code to verify your identity:\n{####}\n\nIf you did not make this request, please email support@abc.com.\n\nThanks,\nThe Abc Team",
            "EmailSubject": "Your verification code",
            "DefaultEmailOption": "CONFIRM_WITH_CODE"
        },
        "SmsAuthenticationMessage": "Your verification code is {####}. ",
        "UserAttributeUpdateSettings": {
            "AttributesRequireVerificationBeforeUpdate": []
        },
        "MfaConfiguration": "OPTIONAL",
        "DeviceConfiguration": {
            "ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice": true,
            "DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt": true
        },
        "EstimatedNumberOfUsers": 689,
        "EmailConfiguration": {
            "SourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:123456789009:identity/no-reply@abc.com",
            "EmailSendingAccount": "COGNITO_DEFAULT"
        },
        "SmsConfiguration": {
            "SnsCallerArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789009:role/service-role/devmobileappusers-SMS-Role",
            "ExternalId": "8d37769d-08cd-44e7-987a-******************",
            "SnsRegion": "us-east-1"
        },
        "UserPoolTags": {},
        "Domain": "devmobileappusers",
        "AdminCreateUserConfig": {
            "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": false,
            "UnusedAccountValidityDays": 7,
            "InviteMessageTemplate": {
                "SMSMessage": "Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. ",
                "EmailMessage": "Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}. ",
                "EmailSubject": "Your temporary password"
            }
        },
        "UsernameConfiguration": {
            "CaseSensitive": false
        },
        "Arn": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:123456789009:userpool/us-east-2_*********",
        "AccountRecoverySetting": {
            "RecoveryMechanisms": [
                {
                    "Priority": 1,
                    "Name": "verified_email"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Second one I have created on **August 23, 2023**. The following is the configuration:

```
{
    "UserPool": {
        "Id": "us-east-2_***********",
        "Name": "devint-mobileapp-users",
        "Policies": {
            "PasswordPolicy": {
                "MinimumLength": 8,
                "RequireUppercase": true,
                "RequireLowercase": true,
                "RequireNumbers": true,
                "RequireSymbols": true,
                "TemporaryPasswordValidityDays": 7
            }
        },
        "DeletionProtection": "ACTIVE",
        "LambdaConfig": {
            "PreSignUp": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789098:function:dev-mobileapp-users-presignup-trigger"
        },
        "LastModifiedDate": "2024-02-15T10:30:19.365000+05:30",
        "CreationDate": "2023-08-23T16:00:18.471000+05:30",
        "SchemaAttributes": [
            {
                "Name": "sub",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": false,
                "Required": true,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "1",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "name",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "given_name",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "family_name",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "middle_name",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "nickname",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "preferred_username",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "profile",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "picture",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "website",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "email",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": true,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "email_verified",
                "AttributeDataType": "Boolean",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false
            },
            {
                "Name": "gender",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "birthdate",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "10",
                    "MaxLength": "10"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "zoneinfo",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "locale",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "phone_number",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": true,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "phone_number_verified",
                "AttributeDataType": "Boolean",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false
            },
            {
                "Name": "address",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "0",
                    "MaxLength": "2048"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "updated_at",
                "AttributeDataType": "Number",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "NumberAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinValue": "0"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "custom:internal-token",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "5"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "custom:user_token",
                "AttributeDataType": "String",
                "DeveloperOnlyAttribute": false,
                "Mutable": true,
                "Required": false,
                "StringAttributeConstraints": {
                    "MinLength": "1"
                }
            }
        ],
        "AutoVerifiedAttributes": [
            "email"
        ],
        "UsernameAttributes": [
            "email"
        ],
        "VerificationMessageTemplate": {
            "DefaultEmailOption": "CONFIRM_WITH_CODE"
        },
        "UserAttributeUpdateSettings": {
            "AttributesRequireVerificationBeforeUpdate": []
        },
        "MfaConfiguration": "OPTIONAL",
        "DeviceConfiguration": {
            "ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice": true,
            "DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt": true
        },
        "EstimatedNumberOfUsers": 577,
        "EmailConfiguration": {
            "SourceArn": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-2:123456789098:identity/no-reply@abc.com",
            "EmailSendingAccount": "COGNITO_DEFAULT"
        },
        "SmsConfiguration": {
            "SnsCallerArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789098:role/service-role/stagingmobileappusers-SMS-Role",
            "ExternalId": "3f0cc307-d5dd-44be-96ff-************",
            "SnsRegion": "us-east-1"
        },
        "UserPoolTags": {},
        "Domain": "devint-appusers",
        "AdminCreateUserConfig": {
            "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": false,
            "UnusedAccountValidityDays": 7
        },
        "UsernameConfiguration": {
            "CaseSensitive": false
        },
        "Arn": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:123456789098:userpool/us-east-2_********",
        "AccountRecoverySetting": {
            "RecoveryMechanisms": [
                {
                    "Priority": 1,
                    "Name": "verified_email"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the sample code for my **MFA with SMS** setup:

```
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
      region: 'us-east-2', 
      userPoolId: 'us-east-2_FSabCdeff', 
      userPoolWebClientId: '2lehdjcn73nnfmmjfnvgg53'
  }
});

var globalUser = null

async function signIn(event) {
  try {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('event::',event)
    const username = event.currentTarget.elements.usernameInput.value;
    const password = event.currentTarget.elements.passwordInput.value
      const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
      globalUser = user
      console.log('user: ', user);

  } catch (error) {
      console.log('error signing in', error);
  }
}

async function verify2FA(event) {
  try {
    event.preventDefault();
    const otpCode = event.currentTarget.elements.otpField.value;
    const loggedUser = await Auth.confirmSignIn( globalUser, otpCode, 'SMS_MFA' );
      console.log('user: ', loggedUser);
      const result = await Auth.rememberDevice();
      console.log('Remember:',result);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('error verifying otp', error);
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    ______________________________________________
    <h2>Sign in</h2>
    <form onSubmit={signIn}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="usernameInput">Username:</label>
        <input id="usernameInput" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="passwordInput">Password:</label>
        <input id="passwordInput" type="text" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    ______________________________________________

    ______________________________________________
    <h2>MFA - SMS</h2>
    <form onSubmit={verify2FA}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="otpField">OTP:</label>
        <input id="otpField" type="text" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    ______________________________________________
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Remember device and suppress MFA for subsequent logins are working fine for `dev-mobileapp-users` user pool. But for the other user-pool, **it is always prompting for MFA**. When I compare the configurations, everything looks the same. I am not getting why this issue is happening. Is this some problem with Cognito or any configuration mismatch from my end. I don't know.

But one point I have noticed is that, for `dev-mobileapp-users` in the **Device tracking log** section, I can see the device I used to login as **Remembered = YES** with a full **Name of the device**.

At the same time for the other user-pool, the **Device tracking log** section is showing my device as **Remembered = YES**, but **Name** is showing as **empty** (-).

I am wondering why the same code is behaving differently on 2 user-pools though the configurations are the same.

Any thoughts on this problem?